# Excel 2013: moving X-Axis values to the middle of the columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

How could I move the X-Axis values to the middle of the columns?

For example, the month values in the chart below (it's not my chart, it the state I want to reach) appear in the middle of the column. How could i do it?

[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You ask how to move them, yet show the months are already in the middle. Can you please clarify?

Comment: It's a picture that show the *result* i want to reach. It's not my example. Will edit the question to emphasise it.

Comment: Can you also include a picture of what yours looks like now?

Comment: I don't know how to get the axis labels not to be centered. Show us the chart with uncentered labels.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Office 2013 there's an option on the chart to edit the elements, from there you need to go to Format Axis -> Axis Options -> Vertical Axis Crosses. You can then set the crossing point based on the category number.

Comment: Tried it (with the Horizontal Axis, the one I need), doesn't affect the chart in any way...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you resolved your question but what might work is putting a space in a sub-title/category row (row below Market A and Market B).  The result is graph that centers your primary title, however there is a gap between the Axis label and data bars (see Graph).  This gap can be minimized to by going to Format Axis -> Axis Options -> Label distance from axis and changing it to zero.  Hope this helps.

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3WEH.png)

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlxyC.png)